# How much VRAM on each iPhone/iPod model?

Tags: iphone, memory, bandwidth, capacity

I know MBX model has limit of 24MB VRAM. How about SGX models?
And can I assume all iPhone/iPod touch models have SGX or MBX at least? No other models?
And how much memory bandwidth (to/from GPU) they have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is VRAM: the video hardware takes (maps) memory from the real main memory.

You can make *some* assumptions about memory available for textures and buffers but you have to be really careful with that. There is most certainly a difference between older and newer models of both the iPod Touch and iPhone when it comes to available memory.

You can check the CPU and OpenGL ES capabilities at runtime. Do that instead of looking at a specific device model.

Comment: No official specification or guidelines about memory capability???
It's really hard to believe!